# Bonkers PHP Months?

Tags: php, date

Here is a basic proof-of-concept script:

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++)
{
    echo 'Using ' . $i . ' | ';
    echo date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$i)) . " | ";
    echo date('F', strtotime('2011-' . $i . '-01')) . "<br />";
}
```

And the output I get is:

```
Using 1 | January | January
Using 2 | March | February
Using 3 | March | March
Using 4 | April | April
Using 5 | May | May
Using 6 | June | June
Using 7 | July | July
Using 8 | August | August
Using 9 | September | September
Using 10 | October | October
Using 11 | November | November
Using 12 | December | December
```

### What happened to February??

This is killing me as it just stopped showing February and started showing March.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) incorrectly.

```
int mktime ([ int $hour = date("H") 
            [, int $minute = date("i") 
            [, int $second = date("s") 
            [, int $month = date("n") 
            [, int $day = date("j")  <------------ here 
            [, int $year = date("Y") <------------ and here
            [, int $is_dst = -1 ]]]]]]] )
```

If you don't specify `$day` and `$year`, they will default to *today's date*.

Today is the 30th, which doesn't exist in February.

This will work:

```
echo date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,2011)) . " | ";
```

Answer (score 3):

Quite simple - you're running this on the 29th, 30th, or 31st of the month. `mktime(0,0,0,2)` is really `mktime(0,0,0,2,date('j'),date('Y'))`, which in the case of today would try to create February 30th 2011, which is March 2nd.

Answer (score 1):

[From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php):

> Arguments may be left out in order
>   from right to left; any arguments thus
>   omitted will be set to the current
>   value according to the local date and
>   time.

Thus, it sets the fifth argument to the current day (30 here). Which means it adds to the date, since 30 is an invalid day in February, and makes it march.

Comment: Feb 30th = Mar 2nd, basically (unless it's a leap year, in which case it's Mar 1st).

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php#77490